# jQuery add remove tr from table after click in every td and passing data

Tags: jquery, html-table, click

I've a table with more tr and td:

```
<table>
<tr>
 <td><a href='1.htm'> 1 </a></td>
 <td><a href='2.htm'> 2 </a></td>
 <td><a href='3.htm'> 3 </a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><a href='4.htm'> 4 </a></td>
 <td><a href='5.htm'> 5 </a></td>
 <td><a href='6.htm'> 6 </a></td>
</tr>


</table>
```

When user clicks on first **td** with `href=1.htm`  a new **tr** after must be created.
In this, a callback Ajax content load. 
When user click on third **td** , the previous **tr** must be replaced (`hidden`) with a new content loaded with Ajax and so on.

Comment: Clicking some `td`s ADDS a `tr`, but clicking other `td`s replaces the existing `tr`? Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

To me, it sounds like what you need is the [jQuery UI tabs widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax).